# Convert bit sequence to uint32_t in c++

Tags: c++, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, uint32

User specifies register (LFSR) length with integer as a parameter for a function, for example he enters number 5. I need to initialize this 5-bit length LFSR with all 1 bits (for length 5 it will be `11111`) and get a seed mask in a format `uint32_t` - for 5-length register it will be `0x0001f`.

What is the best way to get mask `0x0001f` for 5 bit length register when a user enters only length of the register as an integer number 5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To generate a mask of n bits (where n < 32):

```
uint32_t mask = (1U << n) - 1U;
```

---

Explanation: consider the example where n = 5:

```
1U << n = 1U << 5 = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0000 = 0x20
```

then we subtract 1 and get:

```
                    0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 1111 = 0x1f
```

Comment: thank you for explanation - I got it, you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Another option is

```
std::uint32_t mask = ~(~0U << n);
```

Also you have to make sure `unsigned int` isn't less than 32 bits on your system, it may be better to write

```
std::uint32_t mask = ~(~(std::uint32_t)0 << n);
```